# How to concat a scalar to a 1D vector in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a Keras layer of Shape (None, 8) and I would like to append a single scalar (value = 1) to the end of the Tensor. However I haven't been successful.

Here is my code (simplified):

```
print(layers)
# Tensor("feature_layer_2_89/Relu:0", shape=(?, 8), dtype=float32)
pad_tensor = tf.constant([1.0])
concat = concatenate([layers, pad_tensor])
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 8), (1,)]
```

EDIT:
Basically I want to append a scalar (with the value of 1) to a vector. For example given a vector (1D Tensor) `[1 3 3 0 2]`, how to produce `[1 3 3 0 2 1]`, and I don't want to mess with the batch size which is `None` here.

Comment: The `layers` tensor is rank 2, btw, with one dimension unkown size, not 1d. How are you planning to concat a scalar to a 2d vector/tensor?

Comment: @Psidom I thought the first dimension (None) is the batch size and is not considered as real dimension. Is it possible to reshape the `pad_tensor` to rank 2 tensor, similar to `layers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the `pad_tensor` such that it has the rank 2 as @Psidom suggested. So first we need to get the `batch_size` as follows:

```
batch_size = tf.shape(layers)[0]
padding_tensor = tf.ones([batch_size, 1])
```

Now we can use `concatenate` function to concat  the two Tensors:

```
concat = concatenate([layers, padding_tensor])
```

Comment: Thank you! finally, I got it to work.
this should be trivial but keras is stupid about dimensions.